# Push Notifications: Navigate to a ViewController from the AppDelegate

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin, push-notification

Currently, I am working to refine an iOS app I'm currently working on, by adding push notifications. These push notifications get send to people to notify them there's an action to be taken inside the app.

I am currently working on implementing the "when you're inside the app and you get a notification"-part: the `ReceivedRemoteNotification`.

Now, since this method needs to be implemented inside the AppDelegate, there's no way for me to just say `NavigationController.PushViewController (viewController, true);`. Creating a new NavigationController didn't work.

So, now I'm wondering: is there a way to get the `NavigationController` that has been initialised (because I've already opened the app), so that I can then use the `PushViewController` method?

Or is there another way to navigate to a `ViewController` from within the AppDelegate?

Comment: Could you try to send a NSNotification from APPDelegate when you receive a push notification and observe for this in your current controller (or NavigationController) and make your push then?

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin/C# the root view controller for your app is:

```
UIViewControler rootViewController = this.window.RootViewController;
```

This should look familiar from your override of FinishedLaunching in the AppDelegate. From there you should be able to navigate the view hierarchy to get your user to the right place.

Comment: Unfortunately, the RootViewController is a custom controller, that has 4 NavigationControllers in it. There's no way for me to determine in which NavigationController I'm currently working.

Comment: Even if it's a custom controller, you can cast from the rootViewController to your custom type, and then create methods in there to allow you to do whatever you want. So if your push notification required a certain screen to be on the second navigation controller in your customer controller, you should be able to create a method on the custom controller to do exactly that.

Comment: Ah, I see! Yes, that's something I've never thought about! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this to get a reference to the root controller in your app

(hopefully its the nav controller you are looking for):

```
//////////////AppDelegate.m

UINavigationController *currentNavController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController
```